# Encrypt ID in the URL using Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel 4, and I am trying to develop a simple employee CRUD system.

If I want to update a record, I have to access "domain/laravel/employee/1" it means that **"1"** represents as employee ID. Is there a function in Laravel 4 that I can set to encrypt the ID automatically?

Or maybe there is a better way instead of ID encryption?

Comment: That id is a simple auto-incrementing number. It's not really suitable for use as some kind of secret employee ID, if only because everybody will know the ID of the person hired before and after them. You should generate random secret employee IDs.

Comment: Let say User A can only access Employee A(1) and B(2), what if User A tries to change the URL and get information of Employee C(3) then user can just manipulate the URL.

Comment: Then you need to use real authentication, not simply try to produce "encrypted" IDs. That is security through obscurity at its worse. The URL is not a security feature, don't treat it like such.

Comment: I get your idea that the authentication should be done in server rather than relying on ID encryption. I might also consider random secret employee ID stored in my table. Thanks!

Comment: If you want less predictable values for id, use a guid/uuid

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best practice. If you encrypt the id using `Crypt::encrypt($id)`, then the url will be

`domain/laravel/employee/eyJpdiI6IjltdEJraDN3SWdGa21hTktodWdq`

This is not easily predictable. Use `Crypt::decrypt($id)` to decrypt the id.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you have to follow 2 steps

1. encrypt id in blade file
   **`<a href="/product/{{ encrypt($product->id) }}">Delete</a>`**
2. decrypt id in controller or web.php file
   **$decrypted_id = decrypt($id);**